# Radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{c_{n}}{1+\left|c_{n}\right|}z^{n} $

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Given $$ ROC\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}z^{n}\right)=R $$
I used the root test and figured that:$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|c_{n}\left|z\right|^{n}\right|}<1\Rightarrow\left|z\right|\sqrt[n]{c_{n}}<1\Rightarrow\left|z\right|<\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{c_{n}}}=R\Rightarrow\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{c_{n}}=\frac{1}{R} $$
Now I did the same root test with the given series $$ \sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{c_{n}}{1+\left|c_{n}\right|}z^{n}\right|}=\left|z\right|\sqrt[n]{\frac{c_{n}}{1+\left|c_{n}\right|}}<1\Rightarrow\left|z\right|<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+\left|c_{n}\right|}}{\sqrt[n]{c_{n}}} $$
Divided into 2 cases.

Case 1.:$$ if\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|c_{n}\right|>1\Rightarrow\sqrt[n]{1+\left|c_{n}\right|}<\sqrt[n]{2\left|c_{n}\right|}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{R} $$
Case 2:$$ if\,\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|c_{n}\right|<1\Rightarrow\sqrt[n]{1+\left|c_{n}\right|}<\sqrt[n]{2}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1 $$
So there are two options for:$$ \sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{c_{n}}{1+\left|c_{n}\right|}z^{n}\right|}=\left|z\right|\sqrt[n]{\frac{c_{n}}{1+\left|c_{n}\right|}}<1\Rightarrow\left|z\right|<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+\left|c_{n}\right|}}{\sqrt[n]{c_{n}}}=\frac{\frac{1}{R}}{\frac{1}{R}}=1\,or\,\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R}}=R $$

So I'm not sure, which is it?

Comment: how about $\lim|c_n|=1$?

Comment: seems to fit into case 2, but why is this case important?

Comment: You should have $\limsup$ instead of $\lim$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $R'$ denote the radius of convergence of the  series
$$\sum {c_n\over 1+|c_n|}z^n$$
As ${|c_n|\over 1+|c_n|}\le 1,$ we get $R'\ge 1.$

(a) Assume $R<1,$ i.e. $\limsup|c_n|^{1/n}>1.$ Thus
$|c_{n_k}|>1$ for a subsequence $n_k$ of natural numbers.
Therefore
$${|c_{n_k}|\over 1+|c_{n_k}|}> {1\over 2}$$
Hence $R'\le 1,$ i.e. $R'=1.$

(b) Assume $R>1.$ Then the series $\sum |c_n|$ is convergent. In particular $\lim|c_n|=0.$ Thus $|c_n|\le 1$ for $n$ large enough. Hence
$${1\over 2}|c_n|\le {|c_n|\over 1+|c_n|}\le |c_n|,\qquad n\ge N$$
Therefore  $R'=R.$

(c) $R=1.$ For $0<\delta<1$ there is a subsequence $n_k$ such that
$$|c_{n_k}|^{1/n_k}\ge \delta$$
Hence $|c_{n_k}|\ge \delta^{n_k}$ which implies
$${|c_{n_k}|\over  1+|c_{n_k}|}\ge {\delta^{n_k}\over 1+\delta^{n_k}}$$ As $\delta^{n_k}$ tends to $0$ we have
$${|c_{n_k}|\over  1+|c_{n_k}|}\ge {1\over 2}\delta^{n_k},\quad k\ge K$$
and consequently
$$\limsup {|c_n|^{1/n}\over (1+|c_n|)^{1/n}}\ge \delta $$
Thus $R'\le \delta^{-1}.$ As $\delta<1$ is arbitrary we get $R'\le 1.$ Hence $R'=1.$

The final conclusion is $R'=\max(1,R).$

Comment: mostly understood. just a small question, why can we use $|c_n| $ and $c_n$ interchangeably, if it's a complex sequence?

Comment: The radii of convergence of the series $\sum a_nz^n$ and $\sum |a_n|z^n$ are equal.